# Sum only numeric values in object array

Tags: javascript

Given this kind of array

```
const arr = [{
    a: 12,
    b: "A"
    c: 17
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: "B"
    c: 17
  },
  {
    a: 12,
    b: "C"
    c: 17
  }
];
```

What is most efficient way to sum all objects in the array? The result would be `[29,29,29]`

I tried `arr.map(a => Object.values(a).reduce((p,c) => p+c))`
but this would append the non-numeric values to the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter values based on type before reducing

```js
const arr = [{a: 12,b: "A",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "B",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "C",c: 17}];

let final = arr.map(a => Object.values(a).filter(v => typeof v === 'number').reduce((p, c) => p + c))

console.log(final)
```

Or you can do this in reduce method itself, add the current value based on it's type, if type is number add it else add 0

```js
const arr = [{a: 12,b: "A",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "B",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "C",c: 17}];

let final = arr.map(a => Object.values(a).reduce((p, c) => p + (typeof c === 'number' ? c : 0)))

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could directly reduce the value with a check for finiteness.

```js
const
    array = [{ a: 12, b: "A", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "B", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "C", c: 17 }],
    result = array.map(o => Object
        .values(o)
        .reduce((s, v) => s + (isFinite(v) && v), 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The result depends on how you want to consider possible construction {a: "12"} as a number or as a string.
In this case version with isFinite function will give you wrong result.

So if you want to consider {a: "12"} as a number you may use this code:

```js
const
    array = [{ a: "12", b: "A", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "B", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "C", c: 17 }],
    result = array.map(o => Object
        .values(o)
        .reduce((s, v) => s += +v || 0, 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

if you want to consider {a: "12"} as a string you may use this code:

```js
const
    array2 = [{ a: "12", b: "A", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "B", c: 17 }, { a: 12, b: "C", c: 17 }],
    result2 = array2.map(o => Object
        .values(o)
        .reduce((s, v) => s += (typeof v === 'number') ? v : 0, 0)
    );

console.log(result2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement it like this:

```js
arr = [{a: 12,b: "A",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "B",c: 17},{a: 12,b: "C",c: 17}];

var result=Object.values(arr).reduce((acc, elem)=>{
   let kevValue=Object.entries(elem), result=0;
   kevValue.forEach(([k,v])=>{if(!isNaN(v))result+=v;});
   acc.push(result);
   return acc;
},[]);
console.log(result);
```